# How can I simplify this Android program?

Tags: android, performance

I just started learning Android/Java programming. This is my first basic program and it is working fine now. Thanks to the Stack overflow folks for helping me out. Now it would be really helpful if you can help me in tuning this program, it will give me a better understanding of the basic structure of Android programming. Here is the code...  (Brief: It will convert Celsius to Fahrenheit and vice versa as you type..)

```
 package mag.com.myhelloworldapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText celsiusText;
     private EditText farenheitText;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        celsiusText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        farenheitText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        celsiusText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2)).setText("");
                ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).setText("");
            }
        });

        farenheitText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2)).setText("");
                ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).setText("");
            }
        });


        farenheitText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence S, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                if(farenheitText.hasFocus())
                {
                float inputValue;
                if (!S.toString().equals(""))
                {
                    inputValue = Float.parseFloat(S.toString());
                             ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).setText(String
                                    .valueOf(convertFahrenheitToCelsius(inputValue)));

                }
                else
                {
                     ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).setText("");
                    return;
                }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {

            }
        });


        celsiusText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                   }

                   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
                     int count, int after) {
                   }
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence S,int start,int before, int count){
                    if (celsiusText.hasFocus())
                    {
                    float inputValue;

                    if (!S.toString().equals(""))
                    {
                        inputValue = Float.parseFloat(S.toString());
                     ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2)).setText(String
                                .valueOf(convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(inputValue)));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2)).setText("");
                        return;
                    }
                            }
                }
                });       


    }



//Converts to celsius
      private float convertFahrenheitToCelsius(float fahrenheit) {
        return ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9);
      }

      // Converts to fahrenheit
      private float convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(float celsius) {
        return ((celsius * 9) / 5) + 32;
      }


    }
```

This is activity_main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="@string/celsius"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
        android:text="@string/fahrenheit"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks again for your help..

Comment: Why modify if it's working fine. Write another one, instead.

Comment: Since the app runs fine and you only want help streamlining it. This question might be a better fit for [CodeReview (Beta)](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You are right Alex,but I just want to understand what are all the basic mistakes I'm doing. This self check will help me to right a better code next time.

Comment: What basic mistakes are you doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of :

```
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2)).setText("");
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).setText("");
```

you should simply reuse the one you have already like this:

```
celsiusText.setText("");
farenheitText.setText("");
```

no point on finding the View every time when you already have the objects assigned.

This of course for all the places in your code where you use:

```
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1))
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see right now:

Once you have stored the views from XML in variables, you don't need to search for them again (findViewById). Just use the variables you created instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Lxx. I will change the code for the first suggestion. I 've a doubt for the second one though, the condition .hasfocus was checked because, if I edit the text in celsiustext, the Fahrenheit will change automatically, as a result it is failing with stack overflow error. To overcome that I'm checking if the changing text box has focus then go ahead and update the other Edit text.. Is my understanding correct?